# Como realizar una herencia en typescript de un modelo de Prisma?

Tags: mysql, nodejs, typescript

Buen dia, queria consultar si alguno sabia como realizar una herencia desde un modelo de Prisma, a crear una clase personalizada en mi proyecto y hacer que herede los atributos del modelo de Prisma.

Por ejemplo:
Estos son mis modelos en Prisma:

```
generator client {
provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model entityType {
  id    Int     @id @default(autoincrement()) @map("entidadTipoId")
  email String  @unique 
  name  String? @map("nombre")

  @@map("entidad_tipo")
}
```

Ahora bien, yo quiero crear una clase que se llama "EntityType" en mi proyecto y que herede de la clase "entityType" de Prisma, por ejemplo:

```
import {PrismaClient}  from '@prisma/client'

export default class EntityType extends PrismaClient['entityType']
{ 
    constructor(id:number,name:string,email:string)
    {
      super(id,name,email)   
    }
}
```

Quisiera saber si podria hacerlo heredar y que esta clase tome todos los metodos de ese modelo de PrismaClient['entityType'], es decir declarar un objeto nuevo de la siguiente manera:

```
var Res = new EntityType(1,"","");
Res.aggregate(Res);
```

Y que de esta forma guarde en mi base de datos, o algo similar, espero haber sido claro! Gracias.